# How would I make a fake signature with behat

Tags: php, selenium, bdd, behat, mink

[Picture of tested code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaoU2.png) / [Picture of working signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW7fL.png) Hello I am using behat with the selenium driver integrated with mink and I am trying to write a test that inputs a fake signature. We use the mouse to draw the signature on the screen so I want to be able to have selenium do that for me. I tried grabbing the Id of the field and using dragTo('another element on my page'), but it only clicks inside the signature box and doesnt do anything else.

The framework I am using is laravel for php.

```
$field = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findById('ctlSignature);

$field->dragTo('another id on my page');
```

This does not work.

If I can tell the mouse to click then move 10 pixels to the right then click again that would be perfect as I can use that to draw a signature.

---

Thank you for the response but when I run this code I get a error,

```
$script = "var c = document.querySelector('#ctlSignature'); var ctx = c.getContext('2d'); ctx.moveTo(20,20); ctx.lineTo(50,50); ctx.stroke()";

$this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);
```

Sends a error back Unexpected token var. If i try to use  inside the string it sends another error saying unexpected token

Comment: What framework are the devs using for the signature feature? is a jQuery based canvas or something else?

Comment: Ahh ok, yea we are using SuerSignature.js, their website is www.SuperSignature.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to use a javascript that you can execute with evaluateScript or executeScript.

```
$this->getSession()->evaluateScript($script);
```

The $script variable is a string that could contain a script like:

```
var c = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(50,50);
ctx.stroke();
```

If needed you can change the values of the draw by using variables.

Tested in the browser so it works, what you need to make sure is to switch to the iframe that contains the canvas, if any.

Please see bellow step with same script but slightly changed to write text:

```
   /**
     * @Then /^signature test$/
     */
    public function signatureTest(){
        $script = 'var c = document.querySelector("canvas"); var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); ctx.fillStyle = "black"; ctx.font = "20px Georgia"; ctx.fillText("automation user",10,90);';
        $this->getSession()->executeScript($script);
    }
```

Make sure the selector used will select the canvas element type.

Second version, try mousedown event trigger.

```js
    /**
     * @Then /^signature test$/
     */
    public function signatureTest(){
        $function = <<<JS
        (function(){
        var c = document.querySelector("canvas");

        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
        event.initEvent('mousedown', true, true);

        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.font = "20px Georgia";
        ctx.fillText("automation user",10,90);

        c.dispatchEvent(event);
        })()
JS;
        $this->getSession()->executeScript($function);
    }
```

Comment: Response to this is in the original question, thank you.

Comment: So with that I can get it to write on the screen but it doesnt accept it as a signature. It seems to require it to be a mouse down event to accept the signature.

Comment: ok, then it might work if a onmousedown event is trigger, i will try few things

Comment: I highly appreciate it lauda!

Comment: Almost, the ctx.fillText I took out as the form you cant type in its signed all by mouse. So you hold the left click and sign the form by moving the mouse. I was trying to play with it but I still had no luck. Pretty much I need to tell the code to start it this pixel mouse down and hold, then move to this pixel. From that pixel set another path and repeat at the end mouse up.

Comment: I was trying to add a pic but it says I dont have enough rep points yet....

Comment: Have you tried to replace ctx.fillStyle+ ctx.font+ ctx.fillText with ctx.moveTo+ ctx.lineTo+ ctx.stroke front the first script? If you have any UX dev in the team I am sure he could easily adapt this script.