# Not able to draw on canvas using selenium webdriver version 2.53.1 in Internet Explorer browser

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, canvas, gis

I have a GIS-based application to test, I want to draw certain shapes on a canvas in Internet Explorer browser, but the control is not clicking on the web canvas element. my code is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla browsers but I need to make it work in IE also(IE11 to be precise).

My Code Is:

```
    WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='map']/div/canvas"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement canvasElement = null;
    org.openqa.selenium.Point point = image.getLocation();
    int xcord = point.getX();
    System.out.println("Element's Position from left side Is "+xcord +" pixels.");
    int ycord = point.getY();
    System.out.println("Element's Position from top side Is "+ycord +" pixels.");
    builder.clickAndHold(canvasElement).moveByOffset(150, 100).
    moveByOffset(180,100).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    builder.clickAndHold(canvasElement).moveByOffset(-100,-150).doubleClick().moveByOffset(180,200).moveByOffset(-220,-170).doubleClick().click()
    .build().perform();
```

Comment: Maybe share your code?

Comment: Please post it formatted inside your question. You can click 'edit' to change your question's content

Comment: Why not use the canvas js api and execute a script? see here an example of the javascript that you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479033/how-would-i-make-a-fake-signature-with-behat