# How to test canvas using selenium

Tags: selenium, canvas

Is there any way how to test canvas using selenium?

For example:

- test if in canvas is red circle
- move action
- etc

Comment: See if you can use some canvas api via javascript. A simple example is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479033/how-would-i-make-a-fake-signature-with-behat

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Selenium with OpenCV like described here:

http://hacklabos.org/2019/02/python-html5-canvas-game-web-automation-example-using-selenium-and-opencv/

Import example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.tripletsandus.com/80s/80s_games/html5_galaga.htm")
…
def get_driver_image(driver):
canvas_base64 = driver.execute_script("return 
arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", a)
cap = base64.b64decode(canvas_base64)
global image
global gray_image
image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(cap, np.uint8), 1)
```

After that you can do magic with OpenCV, for example:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/15/determining-object-color-with-opencv/